# Oracle SQL group by returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Here is my table

[image]

And here comes my query (Oracle SQL) :

```
SELECT col_1, sum(col_2)
FROM table
GROUP BY col_1
```

I then expect to have as result :

[image]

But, outcome of this query is :

[image]

This is unexpected behavior from my understanding. Indeed, it seems that SQL consider col_3 to calculate result (A, X and A,Y combinations). But, to me, col_3 is not selected so it should not be taken into consideration to group by data.

I may have missed how to proceed with such cases.

Thanks in advance for your help to build up my knowledge :)

Comment: Is your current result what you really see - or does it have two rows with ‘A’? (And please post formatted text, not images.) Check that there is no whitespace in `col_1`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data. I cannot replicate your output [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uYb3D-nf) so you need to give us some way of repeating your results.

Comment: Even after changing the `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP` session parameters and using accents in the data [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FLMidYHa) I cannot replicate your output.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected result. A instead of 1.

Comment: what is the outcome if you run the following query? `select dump(col_1), col_1, col_2_tot from (select col_1, sum(col_2) col_2_tot from table group by col_1);`?

Comment: Boneist. It works with select col_1, sum(col_2) from (select col_1, col_2 from table) group by col_1. Included query is created a table without col_3. But this does not look really elegant solution as it is not really straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a trailing whitespace character (or an zero-width character) in one row.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
SELECT 'A',  1, 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A ', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     -- Note the trailing space!
SELECT 'A',  2, 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  1, 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  1, 'X' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT col_1, DUMP(col_1) FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

| COL_1 | DUMP(COL_1) |
| --- | --- |
| A | Typ=1 Len=1: 65 |
| A | Typ=1 Len=2: 65,32 |
| A | Typ=1 Len=1: 65 |
| B | Typ=1 Len=1: 66 |
| C | Typ=1 Len=1: 67 |

You can see that the 2nd row has an extra character with the ASCII code 32 (which is a space character).

And:

```sql
SELECT col_1,
       sum(col_2)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY col_1;
```

Outputs:

| COL_1 | SUM(COL_2) |
| --- | --- |
| `B` | 1 |
| `A` | 1 |
| `C` | 1 |
| `A` | 3 |

Where there is, correctly, an `A` and an `A`  group.

If you want to ignore the trailing space then:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(col_1) AS col_1,
       sum(col_2)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY RTRIM(col_1);
```

| COL_1 | SUM(COL_2) |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| A | 4 |

Or else, `UPDATE` the table to remove the trailing spaces from `col_1`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3FSqDNfm)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But no space. All 'A' are 'A' without space.

Comment: @KiHEdER Without some difference in the values, it is impossible for the SQL engine to not aggregate the rows together. Did you use `DUMP` to check the binary values of the columns and check that all the values are identical? See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8BXNI3C3) where visual comparison appears identical but one character is `A` (ASCII A) and the other is `Α` (Greek Capital Letter Alpha).